# In TYPO3 Extbase Repository use statement and like together

Tags: repository, typo3

Following function works. But I wanna use "statement" and "like" together. If I comment out the line with constraint1 and try with:

```
$constraint1 = $query->statement("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title LIKE '" . $text . "%'");
```

...the query doesn't work.

I got an error:

1: PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Qom\QueryObjectModelFactory::_or() must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Qom\ConstraintInterface, instance of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query given, called in [...] on line 439 and defined in [...]\typo3\sysext\extbase\Classes\Persistence\Generic\Qom\QueryObjectModelFactory.php line 122

Function:

```
    /**
    * Test
    *
    * @param string $text
    * @return Objects
    */
    public function findWordsByText($text) {

        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);

        $query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);

        $constraint1 = $query->like('title', $text . '%');
        // $constraint1 = $query->statement("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE title LIKE '" . $text . "%'");

        $constraint2 = $query->like('title', 'new');

        $constraint = array($constraint1, $constraint2);

        $query->matching(
            $query->logicalOr($constraint)
        );

        $records = $query->execute();

        return $records;
    }
```

If I change follwing lines:

```
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalOr($constraint)
    );
```

To - logicalAnd:

```
    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalAnd($constraint)
    );
```

...the query is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your problem. You want to return all records that either contain the term $text in the title field or have 'new' in the title field. So just use a simple logicalOr query:

```
/**
* Test
*
* @param string $text
* @return Objects
*/
public function findWordsByText($text) {

    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE);

    $query->matching(
        $query->logicalOr(
           $query->like('title', '%' . $text . '%'),
           $query->like('title', 'new')
        )
    );

    return $query->execute();
}
```

$query->statement() is for raw SQL queries and cannot be combined with createQuery.

By the way, if $text comes from a POST or GET input, don't forget to sanitize the input.

Comment: Thx for your reply.With constraint1 I want search the pages table and constraint2 is the extension table e.g. tx_example_domain_model_words

Comment: All in all get records from an other table in a repository. "cannot be combined with createQuery"? But if I comment out the line with $constraint1 and use the line under and change line to:

    $constraint = array($constraint1); 

...I get records.

Comment: Can you precise your question with what you're trying to achieve (not just what doesn't work)? What is the relation between the table "pages" and your extension. How are they connected? With createQuery you can only query tables that have an Extbase model, "pages" doesn't have one by default (still you can add one for it). If you write down your goals, I can help you find the best approach.